# Where do I learn more about WPF and Storyboards?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my first time using WPF, I find it extremely convenient, but I am not up to date on all that is (not) possible with it, such as the MVVM, and I'm having trouble finding the right parameters to call in the XAML files.

I am writing an IRC-based game. When someone writes a command, I want that person's avatar to be visible on my (local) application, and depending on what he wrote, I want the avatar to have a different animation. For example, "move a little bit forward, and slash with a sword". I figure I'd use a storyboard to translate the position, and switch to a different .gif sourcefile to slash the sword.

Right now, I am horribly stuck on trying to 'change' a storyboard, like change from 'move forward and backward' to 'jump up and down'. I found some related questions which answer pieces and parts, but I can't put 1 and 1 together. Most likely because I am missing basic WPF knowledge.

So my questions:

Could you give me some sources that help me become comfortable with WPF (coming from a C#/XNA/WinForms background)?

And, could you tell me how to tackle a problem where I want to have multiple images, use the same set of storyboards on all of them, and frequently switch both images and storyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of basic information at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22980/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-1-of-n) CodeProject article series. And [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364529/Animation-using-Storyboards-in-WPF) one talks about storyboard animation.

Comment: Thank you. I found the second source already, but I couldn't figure out how to switch both images and storyboards completely interchangeable. To me, it seemed like I'd have to hardcode storyboards into the XAML and copy-paste it a few times for every image you want to use them for. Maybe after I work through the first source, things will fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation. BOoks. There ARE decent books about WPF.